# Read/parse kannel store file

Tags: binaryfiles, kannel

I have this Kannel store file. It's a binary file generated by Kannel. I want to read messages in it. How can I do it ? Preferably with Python.

Comment: This article is a bit old, but you should have a look to it (it is in C but shows an example of Kannel Store file usage): http://www.blogalex.com/archives/72

Comment: Thanks. I had seen that article. But it still gives out some weird formating. The thing is, I inherited a kannel instance which was storing messages in a binary file. Now i'm implementing a database for future sms, but,... all the previous one aren't easily readable. it's no the ultimate solution.

Comment: I think you may be talking about 2 different things: kannel.store file is an internal file for Kannel, whereas database storage for future messages can be done with sqlbox (still with kannel.store in use it's a different thing).
Your kannel.store file is only here to store messages that are still "in the system", it should not contain the history of messages.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.